# After converting lead it should go to opportunity edit page

Tags: opportunity

After converting lead it goes to account view page, But i want to make it to opportunity edit page..

Is it possible in salesforce Any help

Comment: You can do it, but this is a pretty broad question. I'd suggest reading up on best practices for how to ask a question on stack exchange and see if you can refine this question a bit.

Comment: How can we do that...Is there any help link

Comment: Yes. The stackexchange help is here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard conversion screens, it isn't possible to direct the user to the opportunity instead of the account.

I did a quick search on AppExchange and found this app let's you configure the landing page after converting: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3FRHEA3. (I have not tried it, so can't speak to its quality.) There may be more on AppExchange.